# Loop cuts can no longer be moved?

Tags: edit-mode

I wanted to apply some loop cuts and I noticed that the loop cuts can no longer be slided on the surface of the object like it was possible some versions ago. Can this feature be reenabled? I am using 2.83.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's now a yellow handle for this :).

Or you can press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and it will slide like before.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thats working

Comment: Glad to be of help :).